# Issues trying to join multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

The school in question has two different ways of promoting gifted students in the middle of the school year.  The first to simply promote them to the next grade; the other is to "dual enroll" them in two grades at once.  However, when we give the students their schedule, we just want to report the highest grade in which the student is enrolled.  The query should return said information for any date. If you were to run this query over the sample data for ‘01/15/2013’, it would return:

```
| name  | grade | className |
|-------|-------|-----------|
| Adam  | 8     | Science   |
| Adam  | 8     | English   |
| Alice | 7     | English   |
| Alice | 7     | History   |
| Jack  | 7     | English   |
| Jack  | 7     | Math      |
```

Here are what the tables are structured like:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Class]
(
    classID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Person]
(
    personID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    parentID1 INT,
    parentID2 INT,
    gender VARCHAR(10)
)


CREATE TABLE dbo.AttendanceRecord
(
    attendanceID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    personID INT,
    classID INT,
    [date] SMALLDATETIME,
    CONSTRAINT FK_attendancePerson FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES Person(personID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_attendanceClass FOREIGN KEY (classID) REFERENCES Class(classID)
)


CREATE TABLE dbo.Schedule
(
    personID INT,
    classID INT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_schedulePerson FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES Person(personID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_scheduleClass FOREIGN KEY (classID) REFERENCES Class(classID)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.Enrollment 
(
    personID INT,
    startDate SMALLDATETIME,
    endDate SMALLDATETIME,
    grade INT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_enrollmentPerson FOREIGN KEY (personID) REFERENCES Person(personID)
)
```

Here is the sample data I am working with:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.AttendanceRecord
SELECT 25,123,'03/21/2013'
UNION
SELECT 25,456,'03/21/2013'
UNION
SELECT 25,789,'03/21/2013'
UNION
SELECT 13,147,'03/21/2013'
UNION
SELECT 25,123,'03/22/2013'
UNION
SELECT 82,147,'03/22/2013'
UNION
SELECT 82,456,'03/22/2013'
UNION
SELECT 13,147,'03/23/2013'
UNION
SELECT 25,456,'03/23/2013'
UNION
SELECT 13,456,'03/24/2013'
UNION
SELECT 25,456,'03/28/2013'


INSERT INTO dbo.Class
SELECT 123, 'Math'
UNION
SELECT 456, 'English'
UNION
SELECT 789, 'History'
UNION 
SELECT 258, 'Lunch'
UNION
SELECT 147, 'Science'

INSERT INTO dbo.Person
SELECT 25, 'Jack', 255, NULL, 'Male'
UNION
SELECT 13, 'Jill', 100, 101, 'Female'
UNION
SELECT 82, 'Adam', NULL, 200, 'Male'
UNION
SELECT 100, 'Jeff', NULL, NULL, 'Male'
UNION
SELECT 101, 'June', NULL, NULL, 'Female'
UNION
SELECT 200, 'Shirley', NULL, NULL, 'Female'
UNION
SELECT 155, 'Alice', 255, NULL, 'Female'
UNION
SELECT 255, 'Tom', NULL, NULL, 'Male'
UNION
SELECT 19, 'Jake', 100,101, 'Male'


INSERT INTO dbo.Schedule
SELECT 25,123
UNION
SELECT 25,456
UNION
SELECT 25,789
UNION
SELECT 13,147
UNION
SELECT 82,147
UNION
SELECT 82,456
UNION
SELECT 13,456
UNION
SELECT 19,123
UNION
SELECT 19,789
UNION
SELECT 155,456
UNION
SELECT 155,789


INSERT INTO dbo.Enrollment
SELECT 25, '09/01/2012','05/31/2013', 7
UNION
SELECT 25, '03/01/2013','05/31/2013', 8
UNION
SELECT 13, '09/01/2012','05/31/2013', 7
UNION
SELECT 82, '09/01/2012', '12/31/2012', 7
UNION
SELECT 82, '01/01/2013', '05/31/2013', 8
UNION
SELECT 19, '09/01/2012', '05/31/2013', 8
UNION
SELECT 155, '09/01/2012','05/31/2013', 7
```

I have tried using multiple joins to achieve this query but nothing seems to be working. It either shows me a huge list of results I dont want or it throws errors.

```
SELECT P.name, E.grade, C.name AS className
FROM Schedule AS S
JOIN Class AS C ON C.classid = S.classid
JOIN Person AS P ON P.personid = S.personid
JOIN Enrollment AS E ON E.personid = P.personid
```

Now I know this isnt what I need, but its where I am starting. Not sure if this is the correct direction to be heading

Comment: What is the result of your query?

Comment: Result is currently too long to post if that tells you anything. It is essentially listing every single combination I think that would be possible.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify! [mcve]

Comment: _essentially listing every single combination I think that would be possible_, JOIN ON 1 = 1.

Comment: Where is your sample data?

Comment: The term you should search for is "correlated subquery". That will yield plenty of good articles and examples that should put you on the right track.

Comment: Start here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group. I would close as duplicate, but I;m not sure if your case is a bit more complicated, as you haven't given expected results

Comment: If you already have all the rows with all the grades each student is enrolled in, you only need to group them so it only shows one row per student with the greatest grade they are enrolled in. Check out using MAX and GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is not clear and the result provide issues.however the query is

```
SELECT P.NAME,
       C.NAME,
       grade
FROM   (SELECT personid,
               classid,
               Max(grade) grade
        FROM  (SELECT E.personid,
                      A.classid,
                      E.grade
               FROM   (SELECT personid,
                              classid,
                              Min([date]) startDate,
                              Max([date]) endDate
                       FROM   AttendanceRecord
                       GROUP  BY personid,
                                 classid) A
                      JOIN Enrollment E
                        ON E.personid = A.personid
              ---AND A.startDate=E.startDate AND A.endDate=E.endDate
--Data is not clear and it provide no result
              ) AA
        GROUP  BY personid,
                  classid)AB
       JOIN Class C
         ON C.classid = AB.classid
       JOIN Person P
         ON P.personid = AB.personid
```

Comment: Better to wait for clarification since its possible another query might be more efficient or the expected results might be different.

Comment: Yeah this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. I just posted a sample of what the return query should look like, the actual list wouldve been a bit too long to have to type out. I appreciate the help!

Comment: However it does not yield your desired result, there is a inconsistency in your data and that should be fixed. but the query must have a syntax like this. happy to help

Comment: @Xzoh - You should also check out the [suggestion by Angela](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71401995/issues-trying-to-join-multiple-tables/71406159#comment126216234_71401995), which seems simpler, but as always compare the execution plans to see which is best.